# how to use multiple filter in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to filter data from multiple tables so I write query like that and one thing I let you know that both data1 and data2 return same column with different data.

```
$data1 = collect(DB::table('table_1')->get()->toArray());
$data2 = collect(DB::table('table_2')->get()->toArray());
$results = $data1->merge($data2);
if ($request->name!="") {
  $results->when(request('name'), function($q){
    $q->Where('name', request('name'));
  });
}
.
.
.
return $results;
```

But `$results` returns all data and not filter data

Comment: You should first learn query building. That all can and should be achieved by SQL query.
I see that you don't know basics but want advanced solution

Comment: that's why i am here you can guide me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$data1 = collect(DB::table('table_1')->get()->toArray());
$data2 = collect(DB::table('table_2')->get()->toArray());
$results = $data1->merge($data2);
if ($request->name!="") {
  $filter_results = $results->when($request->name, function($q){
    $q->where('name', $request->name);
  });
}
.
.
.
return  $filter_results;
```

Comment: it return null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $data1 = collect(DB::table('table_1')->get()->toArray());
 $data2 = collect(DB::table('table_2')->get()->toArray());
 $results = $data1->merge($data2);

 $results->when($request->name, function($q) use($request){
    $q->where('name', $request->name);
  });

return $results;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you . I will try to give a better answer